# Visual Studio and MS Access connection problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

Problem is: I can't connect my MS Access database to my Visual Studio ASP.NET code.

Before I will explain the problem, my PC is 64 bit, I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, and MS Access 2016 (of Office 365).

First of all I imported the OleDb class that helps with the connection between the code and the database.

I have a connection class, called `Connect`:

```
public class Connect
{
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        string FILE_NAME = "Database3.accdb";
        string location = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + FILE_NAME);
        string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=" + location;
        return ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

(the database is obviously located in the App_Data folder, inside the project folder.)

I wrote this, as an `OnClick` handler (when pressing a button which is on the screen) to connect to the database:

```
protected void DatabaseConnect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection();
    Conn.ConnectionString = Connect.GetConnectionString();

    Conn.Open();
    Conn.Close();  
}
```

The problem is the connection string, I am almost 100% sure.

It raises an exception, obviously when the `Conn.Open();` line runs:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' is not registered on internal computer.

Any suggestions or fixes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look up that error message. The first hit I found (granted, it was for another version) was https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/winautomation/support-tips/databases/ace-oledb-12-0-provider-not-registered-on-local-machine. OLEDB drivers need to be properly registered in order to work

Comment: "Provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' is not registered on internal computer." seems like a pretty clear error message to me. You you have the Access OLEDB drivers installed on the server it's running on?

Comment: Actually, EVEN WHEN you have the ACE drivers installed, you WILL get that message if the bit size of  your project does not match the installed version of the ACE drivers. See below for this explain, but EVEN with the ACE drivers installed, you will get and see that message if your project runs as a different bit size then the ODBC/oleDB drivers for Access. So, it turns out that message is not all that clear, since EVEN AFTER having installed the ACE drivers, you STILL see the message about ACE having not been installed when it fact it has been installed - just the wrong version (bit size)!!!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you did/have installed the Access database drivers?

Then in most cases, next up is to determine which bit size of the Access system you installed.

If your web site is running as x32 bits, then you need to install Access x32 bit drivers.

If your web site is running as x64 bits, then you need to install/use the Access x64 bit drivers.

And this also very much means you should NOT use "ANY CPU" for your site, but in fact force the build/compile to the correct bit size.

So, either you force the web site (IIS) to run as x32 bits, and then use Access x32 drivers.

Or, you force the web site (IIS) and your Web site to run as x64 bits, and then use (install) the Access x64 bit drivers.

So, don't guess, and don't use "ANY" CPU, since that will produce inconsistent results during testing.

And it also results in differing behaviors. For example, Visual Studio 2022 is the first version of VS that is now x64 bits. That means if you use "ANY CPU" and hit F5, then your site is running as x64 bits. But, using vs2019? Well, vs2019 is a x32 bit product, and in most cases "any CPU" will now result in code and a site that runs as x32 bits.

So, either you change in the installed version of the Access drivers to x64 bits, and then ensure your code + site runs as x64 bits (this is the most common setup for web sites, but not for the Access data engine).

However, it is only relative recent (last 2 years) that Office/Access now defaults to a x64 bit version of office, where as previous for 20 years, the default was an x32 bit install of the Access data engine.

Last but not least?

You should make some efforts to avoid Access for a web site, and adopt a real server-based database system. Every site, even the most bottom feeder el-cheap-o web hosting gives some kind of database engine included in even super low-cost monthly plans.

While Access can work on a web site, it not going to save you money, and in most cases not save your time either. However, worse than Access data engine not being thread safe are issues of deployment. With x32 vs x64 bit issues we have more issues and hence more failure points to deal with. A great example of these newfound failure points? The very need for this question on SO!

You can find the Access ODBC/oleDB drivers here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Note when you finally get to the download prompt, you find/see 2 options, one for Access x32 bits, and one for Access x64 bits.

Thus, this:

[image]

So, you have to match up

1. the bit size the web site runs as
2. the MS Access driver to the bit size for the site
3. In Visual Studio, make sure you set the build options to the option chosen for 1 & 2.

So, in fact, all 3 of above must match for your connections to work correctly.